# How to add ul class on nav

Tags: menus, themes

I've been learning to convert HTML to WordPress and want to convert on to class like this:

```
<div class="mainmenu pull-left">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav collapse navbar-collapse">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Shop<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
            <ul role="menu" class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="shop.html">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="product-details.html">Product Details</a></li> 
                <li><a href="checkout.html">Checkout</a></li> 
                <li><a href="cart.html">Cart</a></li> 
                <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li> 
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Blog<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
            <ul role="menu" class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog List</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog-single.html">Blog Single</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li> 
        <li><a href="404.html">404</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This what I've done:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'mytheme_setup' ) ) :
    function wpflex_setup() {  
        register_nav_menus( array(
            'primary' => 'Primary Menu'
        ) );
    }
endif;

wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'top-menu',
    'container'      => '',
    'menu_class'     => 'mainmenu pull-left',
) );
```

How to add class for `ul`?

Answer (score 5):

You already did it the right way. If you take a look in the Documentation for [wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/), you'll see that menu_class is the right option for the UL's class:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'top-menu',
    'container' => '',
    'menu_class'=> 'mainmenu pull-left *add-your-class-here*'
 ) );
```

Comment: Don't forget 'container' => 'ul',

Answer (score 5):

It's simple just you need to add `items_wrap` parameter and add or edit class attr:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'top-menu',
    'container' => false,
    'items_wrap' => '<ul class="nav your_custom_class">%3$s</ul>',
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress creates the default page menu different from the active menus -- those which you create and assign in the backend. There is no direct way to add classes to the UL in page menus, but there are other ways. Try adding this to your functions.php

```
function add_id_and_classes_to_page_menu( $ulclass ) {
  return preg_replace( '/<ul>/', '<ul id="main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav collapse navbar-collapse">', $ulclass, 1 );
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu', 'add_id_and_classes_to_page_menu' );
```

Keep in mind this will replace any existing id and classes, thus I re-added them in the above example. I also added an id="main-menu" for completion.

Comment: Dirty, but this was the only way I could get it to do what I wanted to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is your fixed code. I have tested it add class to ul

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'top-menu',
    'container'      => 'ul',
    'menu_class'     => 'mainmenu pull-left',
) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       <?php 
         wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main Menu' ,
        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
         'container' => ''));
            ?>
```